# Access nested array in Json object in AngularJs code and html code

Tags: html, angularjs

I have below code in my angualrjs controller.

```
function loadAll(){

               MeetingAgendaService.get({id:vm.meetingId},function(result) {

                vm.agendas = result;
                vm.assignees=vm.agendas.assignees;

              });
            }
```

the result of `vm.agendas` is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Ongoing",
    "content": "Whatever",
    "meetingId": 1,
    "meetingMeetingName": "Meeting 1",
    "loggedByAssignee": null,
    "assignees": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "empId": 202,
        "empName": "Wickramarachchi"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "empId": 21,
        "empName": "Samarasinghe"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "test",
    "content": "Testing",
    "meetingId": 1,
    "meetingMeetingName": "Meeting 1",
    "loggedByAssignee": null,
    "assignees": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "empId": 21,
        "empName": "Samarasinghe"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ONgoing",
    "content": "goooooooooooooooooooooo",
    "meetingId": 1,
    "meetingMeetingName": "Meeting 1",
    "loggedByAssignee": null,
    "assignees": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "empId": 202,
        "empName": "Wickramarachchi"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to access the `empName` in inner array `assignees` in my html code.I used

`<td style="text-align: center">{{agenda.assignees.empName}}</td>`

like this in my html code and it's not getting the date. How can I access this inner array in html code and angularjs controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two levels of nested object here.

You have to iterate `agenda`  which is an array, and `assignees` which is an array too. You can easily do this with `ngRepeat`.

```
  <div ng-repeat="ag in agenda">
    <div ng-repeat="assigne in ag.assignees">
      {{assigne.empName}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/kCq7S9PBPuK4ufov0BC3?p=preview